# Фокус при клике на кнопку которая открывает input

Tags: javascript, angular2, angular4, focus

Как сделать фокус на input, который сначала скрыт,но по клику на кнопке открывается ? Атрибут autofocus срабатывает только первый раз, а 'nativeElement' of undefined. На jQuery все просто, но нужно без него сделать.

```
<input type="text" *ngIf="isVisible" #test autofocus>
<button (click)="testAction()">Test</button>

@ViewChild('test') test: ElementRef;
isVisible = false;
testAction() {
this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
this.test.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

---

Другой метод:

```
testAction() {
 this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;

 if (this.test && this.test.nativeElement) {
    setTimeout(() => this.test.nativeElement.focus(), 800);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" *ngIf="isVisible" #test autofocus>
<button (click)="testAction()">Test</button>

@ViewChild('test') test: ElementRef;
isVisible = false;
testAction() {
  this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
const obs = Observable.timer(0).subscribe(()=>{
if(thi.test && this.test.nativeElement){
  this.test.nativeElement.focus();
});
}
```

Comment: Подключил import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
а как timer подключить ?

Comment: таймер import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Дужка от if } потерялась